# on react-navigation v3 navigating without the navigation prop dispatch is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I trying to use the example on [`Navigating without the navigation prop`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html)
 on react-native v3.11.0.

but I got this error:

```
TypeError: NavigationService._navigator.dispatch is not a function
    at Function.navigate (C:\...\NavigationService.js)
```

Can anyone help me what is my mistake?

**Update**:

My Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationActions, StackActions} from 'react-navigation';

export default class NavigationService extends React.Component {
  static _navigator;

  static setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
    NavigationService._navigator = navigatorRef;
  }

  static navigate(routeName, params = null) {
    let options = params == null ? {routeName} : {routeName, params};
      NavigationService._navigator.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate(options));
  }
}
```

and on App.js:

```
  render() {
    return (
          <Navigation
            ref={(navigatorRef) => {
              NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
            }}
          />
    );
  }
```

Comment: could you please share your code here? one more question for you is have you made navigation service?

Comment: Yes, I create a class for my service. post updated with my service code.

Comment: First, I would suggest you try the exact example given in the doc maybe it'll not give any error then change the code as per your requirement.

Comment: I have the same error on the exact example.
I think this problem is for delay because when I add a condition error fixed! 
```
if (NavigationService._navigator.dispatch !== undefined) {NavigationService._navigator.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate(options));}
```

Comment: Looks similar to this reported (and closed) issue - https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6287

Answer (score 0):

your code differs from the documentation. Try using the code in the docs

```
// NavigationService.js

import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params,
    })
  );
}

// add other navigation functions that you need and export them

export default {
  navigate,
  setTopLevelNavigator,
};
```